# How to capture image in vb.net using directshow?

Tags: vb.net, directshow

I managed to use a sample code from the internet but all it does is display image from my webcam. Can someone help me how to capture image using directshow in vb?

Comment: Are you developing the app directly based on DirectShow? Or are you using any third-party SDK?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need [DirectShow.NET](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) to capture in VB.NET because you cannot interface to DirectShow from VB.NET directly. DirectShow.NET comes with [samples](https://sourceforge.net/projects/directshownet/files/DirectShowSamples/2010-February/) including those featuring video capture. CapWMV is addressing the question you posted (it's C# though, you will find other in VB.NET there):

```
Samples\Capture\CapWMV
----------------------
Capture from video capture devices to WMV files.
```